# Magento 2 custom console command to create admin user with role, Laminas service locator issue

Tags: magento2

I am cloning Magento's AdminUserCreateCommand to create my custom command to set the role given in command argument. Plan is to create the user using this module just like as default magento's command without saving role for now and when it works, I would like to save the provided role for user instead of default administrator role. I will further make use of `/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/AdminAccount.php` and will modify `retrieveAdministratorsRoleId()` to set role_name from taken input through this command.

app/code/Mymodule/CreateUser/registration.php

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Mymodule_CreateUser', __DIR__);
```

app/code/Mymodule/CreateUser/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mymodule_CreateUser" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

app/code/Mymodule/CreateUser/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Laminas\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface" type="Laminas\ServiceManager\ServiceManager" />
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Setup\LoggerInterface" type="Magento\Framework\Setup\ConsoleLogger" />
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="AdminUserCreateCommand" xsi:type="object">Mymodule\CreateUser\Console\Command\AdminUserCreateCommand</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

app/code/Mymodule/CreateUser/Console/Command/AdminUserCreateCommand.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Mymodule\CreateUser\Console\Command;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ConsoleLogger;
use Magento\Setup\Model\AdminAccount;
use Magento\Setup\Model\InstallerFactory;
use Magento\User\Model\UserValidationRules;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Question\Question;
use Magento\Setup\Console\Command\AbstractSetupCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class AdminUserCreateCommand extends AbstractSetupCommand
{

    /**
     * @var InstallerFactory
     */
    private $installerFactory;

    /**
     * @var UserValidationRules
     */
    private $validationRules;

    /**
     * @param InstallerFactory $installerFactory
     * @param UserValidationRules $validationRules
     */
    public function __construct(InstallerFactory $installerFactory, UserValidationRules $validationRules)
    {
        $this->installerFactory = $installerFactory;
        $this->validationRules = $validationRules;
        parent::__construct();
    }


    /**
     * Initialization of the command
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('admin:myuser:create')
            ->setDescription('Creates an administrator with role')
            ->setDefinition($this->getOptionsList());
        parent::configure();
    }

    /**
     * Creation admin user in interaction mode.
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface $input
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface $output
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    protected function interact(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        /** @var \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper $questionHelper */
        $questionHelper = $this->getHelper('question');

        if (!$input->getOption(AdminAccount::KEY_USER)) {
            $question = new Question('<question>Admin user:</question> ', '');
            $this->addNotEmptyValidator($question);

            $input->setOption(
                AdminAccount::KEY_USER,
                $questionHelper->ask($input, $output, $question)
            );
        }

        if (!$input->getOption(AdminAccount::KEY_PASSWORD)) {
            $question = new Question('<question>Admin password:</question> ', '');
            $question->setHidden(true);

            $question->setValidator(function ($value) use ($output) {
                $user = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
                $user->setPassword($value);

                $validator = new \Magento\Framework\Validator\DataObject();
                $this->validationRules->addPasswordRules($validator);

                $validator->isValid($user);
                foreach ($validator->getMessages() as $message) {
                    throw new \Exception($message);
                }

                return $value;
            });

            $input->setOption(
                AdminAccount::KEY_PASSWORD,
                $questionHelper->ask($input, $output, $question)
            );
        }

        if (!$input->getOption('admin-role')) {
            $question = new Question('<question>Admin role:</question> ', '');
            $this->addNotEmptyValidator($question);

            $input->setOption(
                'admin-role',
                $questionHelper->ask($input, $output, $question)
            );
        }

        if (!$input->getOption(AdminAccount::KEY_EMAIL)) {
            $question = new Question('<question>Admin email:</question> ', '');
            $this->addNotEmptyValidator($question);

            $input->setOption(
                AdminAccount::KEY_EMAIL,
                $questionHelper->ask($input, $output, $question)
            );
        }

        if (!$input->getOption(AdminAccount::KEY_FIRST_NAME)) {
            $question = new Question('<question>Admin first name:</question> ', '');
            $this->addNotEmptyValidator($question);

            $input->setOption(
                AdminAccount::KEY_FIRST_NAME,
                $questionHelper->ask($input, $output, $question)
            );
        }

        if (!$input->getOption(AdminAccount::KEY_LAST_NAME)) {
            $question = new Question('<question>Admin last name:</question> ', '');
            $this->addNotEmptyValidator($question);

            $input->setOption(
                AdminAccount::KEY_LAST_NAME,
                $questionHelper->ask($input, $output, $question)
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add not empty validator.
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Console\Question\Question $question
     * @return void
     */
    private function addNotEmptyValidator(Question $question)
    {
        $question->setValidator(function ($value) {
            if (trim($value) == '') {
                throw new \Exception('The value cannot be empty');
            }

            return $value;
        });
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function execute(
        InputInterface $input,
        OutputInterface $output
    ) {
        $errors = $this->validate($input);
        if ($errors) {
            $output->writeln('<error>' . implode('</error>' . PHP_EOL . '<error>', $errors) . '</error>');
            // we must have an exit code higher than zero to indicate something was wrong
            return \Magento\Framework\Console\Cli::RETURN_FAILURE;
        }
        $installer = $this->installerFactory->create(new ConsoleLogger($output));
        $installer->installAdminUser($input->getOptions());
        $output->writeln(
            '<info>Created Magento administrator user named ' . $input->getOption(AdminAccount::KEY_USER) . '</info>'
        );
        return \Magento\Framework\Console\Cli::RETURN_SUCCESS;
    }

        /**
     * Get list of arguments for the command
     *
     * @param int $mode The mode of options.
     * @return InputOption[]
     */
    public function getOptionsList($mode = InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED)
    {
        $requiredStr = ($mode === InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED ? '(Required) ' : '');

        return [
            new InputOption(
                AdminAccount::KEY_USER,
                null,
                $mode,
                $requiredStr . 'Admin user'
            ),
            new InputOption(
                AdminAccount::KEY_PASSWORD,
                null,
                $mode,
                $requiredStr . 'Admin password'
            ),
            new InputOption(
                'admin-role',
                null,
                $mode,
                $requiredStr . 'Admin role'
            ),
            new InputOption(
                AdminAccount::KEY_EMAIL,
                null,
                $mode,
                $requiredStr . 'Admin email'
            ),
            new InputOption(
                AdminAccount::KEY_FIRST_NAME,
                null,
                $mode,
                $requiredStr . 'Admin first name'
            ),
            new InputOption(
                AdminAccount::KEY_LAST_NAME,
                null,
                $mode,
                $requiredStr . 'Admin last name'
            ),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Check if all admin options are provided
     *
     * @param InputInterface $input
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function validate(InputInterface $input)
    {
        $errors = [];
        $user = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $user->setFirstname($input->getOption(AdminAccount::KEY_FIRST_NAME))
            ->setLastname($input->getOption(AdminAccount::KEY_LAST_NAME))
            ->setUsername($input->getOption(AdminAccount::KEY_USER))
            ->setRole($input->getOption('admin-role'))
            ->setEmail($input->getOption(AdminAccount::KEY_EMAIL))
            ->setPassword(
                $input->getOption(AdminAccount::KEY_PASSWORD) === null
                ? '' : $input->getOption(AdminAccount::KEY_PASSWORD)
            );

        $validator = new \Magento\Framework\Validator\DataObject();
        $this->validationRules->addUserInfoRules($validator);
        $this->validationRules->addPasswordRules($validator);

        if (!$validator->isValid($user)) {
            $errors = array_merge($errors, $validator->getMessages());
        }

        return $errors;
    }
}
```

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

`php bin/magento admin:myuser:create`

[This is the error I am getting when I execute the command with all required input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA3EG.png)

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be easy to create user as administrator first.

- Magento will insert resources into table authorization_role
  [table authorization_role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SV6xY.png)
- You changed after the type from 'G' to 'U'
- delete all rule from table authorization_rule because it will be all by default
  [authorization_rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5bC4.png)
- Add new authorization_rule using the role already exist

The role should exist before on Database
I think it will be easy to use this mecanism

### Update

The problem comes from class Installer in your constructor. By default, Magento 2 uses this class in the "/setup" folder because the environment is different.
What can I recommad is to delete this class from your constructor and use a Model of USERS, all what you need from this class is this

```
function $ installer-> installAdminUser ($ input-> getOptions ());
```

you can use it otherwise without calling the Installer class using **adminAccountFactory**.

Comment: Thank you Hicham, idea is first to create the admin anyhow with cloned console command and then to use the additional input added in creating admin user by updating the role with input provided instead of `Administrator` which is used static in class I am refering.

Answer (score 1):

```
$installer = $this->installerFactory->create(new ConsoleLogger($output));
```

should this code not be like

```
$this->installerFactory->create([
        'the parameter name' => new ConsoleLogger($output)
        ]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply but this is not the actual problem please check the attached image where the actual error message is shown. I am able to call the function using installerFactory object and there is not error in its initialization or function calling... infact I have cloned Magento's file and what I have done additional is just added my extra argument to take role as a additional input. The error appears in further code execution that is with Laminas service manager which was unable to create the class instance.

Comment: @TarunBhalodia Have you resolved your issue?

Comment: Yes @SmitaKagwade , I have successfully created the extension to use custom command that will create the user with given role.